# Cannot specify a culture in string conversion explicitly when converting nullable decimal (decimal?) to string

Tags: c#, nullable, cultureinfo, non-nullable

I have a property:

```
public decimal? DejanskaKolicina { get; set; }
```

and Resharper shows me:

> specify a culture in string conversion explicitly

But if I use:

```
DejanskaKolicina.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

I always get the message that:

> ToString method has 0 parameter(s) but it is invoked with 1 arguments

If I change the decimal property so that it is no longer nullable then it works. How do I use `ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` on nullable property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That particular `ToString` overload only exists for a `decimal`, so you can make it work by only calling it for a `decimal`:

```
DejanskaKolicina == null ? String.Empty : DejanskaKolicina.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should handle `null` separately, like this:

```
DejanskaKolicina == null ? "N/A" : DejanskaKolicina.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Value property of the nullable object:

```
DejanskaKolicina == null ? "" : DejanskaKolicina.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: If you don't check for null first, and the property is null, you'll get an exception that I understood to be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this example may help you:

**A nullable type can be used in the same way that a regular value type can be used. In fact, implicit conversions are built in for converting between a nullable and non-nullable variable of the same type. This means you can assign a standard integer to a nullable integer and vice-versa:**

```
int? nFirst = null;
int Second = 2; nFirst = Second; // Valid
nFirst = 123; // Valid
Second = nFirst; // Also valid
nFirst = null; // Valid
Second = nFirst; // Exception, Second is nonnullable.
```

In looking at the above statements, you can see that a nullable and nonnullable variable can exchange values as long as the nullable variable does not contain a null. If it contains a null, an exception is thrown. To help avoid throwing an exception, you can use the nullable's HasValue property:

```
if (nFirst.HasValue) Second = nFirst;
```

As you can see, if nFirst has a value, the assignment will happen; otherwise, the assignment is skipped.

Comment: That example doesn't compile: you cannot implicitly convert an `int?` to an `int`. The behaviour you describe is what you get when you add a cast: `Second = (int)nFirst;`.